# Access the object of a specific row in a Bootstrap Table and pass into Modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I have a table where each row is an object and shows certain properties. Each row also has a button which opens a deletion modal which will delete the object on that row from the database. The modal Twig template has access to the array of objects displayed, but I need a way of finding which object to search the DB for and delete.

Here is the twig template code to display the data.

```
{%  for announcement in announcements %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ announcement.content }}</th>
        <td>{{ announcement.isDisplayed() }}</td>
        <td style="float:right;">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#announcementDeleteModal">
                         <span class="fa fa-trash btn-link"></span>
                          Delete announcement
                </button>
```

The modal template, which also has accents to the array `announcements`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="announcementDeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                <span class="fa fa-cat"></span><div>Srsly delete that?</div>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ form_start(deleteForm) }}
            {{ form_end(deleteForm) }}
            <span class="fa fa-cat"></span><div>Srsly delete that?</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                Fine. Keep it.
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code which sends the ajax request. The var `id` is capturing the correct data. I just need to access it via the controller. I tried `$request->get('id')` and `$request->get('id')`,

```
$('.action-button').click(function () {
        alert("ran");
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url:"/admin/announcements",
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (html) {
                alert("success");
               // $(this).parent().parent().remove();

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have an `id` for each `announcement`?

Comment: Yes and twig has access to it in the file

Comment: Then just add that as a value on your button?

Comment: @DarkBee how would I add the value? Looking online seems the best way would be to use JavaScript? I'm new to JS is there any documentation?

Comment: `<button value="{{ announcement.getId() }}">click</button>` - sthing like this

Comment: @DarkBee Okay so I'm able to save the value on the HTML side. The tricky thing is this button displays a Bootstrap dropown with a `delete` and `edit` button. Both open a modal, which I would then use the passed ID in my Symfony controller to either edit or delete the announcement with that ID. I can't figure out how to access the id data within my controller

Comment: see updated ajax request code

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do not understand the question, but I suggest that you can either create a modal for each row element while rendering template or write a custom JS script and pass object ID via data attribute and store it into some hidden field.

Comment: would I store the object ID in the data-'' attribute for the button?

Comment: It depends on your solution, personally I would store it on button, it will be easier to handle things. Then use js events to get that id and store it in your hidden form field for later post procedures.

Comment: Okay I will try that thank you. My modal template is in a separate file. is it possible to  send the data-id data attribute to the separate modal file or would I need to combine them?

Comment: Always look for documentation https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html
you can use 'with'.